# Tutorial || ID's rememberd when removing user's from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, railstutorial.org

I am following the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl

> Explanation: Currently a hundred user's in the database. I create 50 accounts more, they get user id's 101 - 150. Then the admin destroys them. When I then create yet another account, it should get user id 101 because users 101 -150 are no longer there. But it gets 151, so my user id's jump from 100 to 151 with nothing inbetween.

What causes this? There is something wrong then with destroying the accounts? below the files and console output:

The view:

```
(app/views/_user.html.erb)
<li>
 <%= gravatar_for user, size: 50 %>
 <%= link_to user.name, user %>
 <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
   |  <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                            data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
<% end %>
</li>
```

The controller:

```
def destroy
  User.find(params[:id]).destroy
  flash[:success] = "User deleted"
  redirect_to users_url
end
```

The console output when deleting user:

```
Started DELETE "/users/102" for $IP at 2016-03-30 12:11:52 +0000
Processing by UsersController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Kj+2TnvVk8jVrZi1leVeQRAjJbZsKqXAhA1cjK/WNDa4TieY54NdD6OCATNANFR0lh1trhi+ZzvMLhnirZnw+g==", "id"=>"102"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 102]]
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  [["id", 102]]
(10.7ms)  commit transaction
```

Comment: Are you sure your destroy works?

Comment: ids are unique...so once assigned there won't be a new user at that id unless you drop the database and start over completely.

Comment: **“When I then create yet another account, it should get user id 101...”** —this is just wrong. Why would you think it _should_? It should not. For the sake of efficiency in some db engines ids might be even non-integers, besides that they might be non-ordered and non-sequenced. You should not care about how `id` field is constructed: it’s a db engine duty to take care about it.

Comment: Ok than my thinking was wrong. So it's just how it works? The user id's once assigned cannot or should not be used a second time?

Comment: By the way. Fluffykittens? Why the edit for rails? It shows which book I uses?

Answer (score 0):

The table id column is auto increment. For mysql see [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html). Auto increment fields are not used again even if the record is deleted, unless you drop the database or call Alter table on it.

There is good reason why it is done, so that no orphan relations get assigned by mistake which might cause data inconsistencies.

Comment: “Auto increment fields are not used again even if the record is deleted” —this is wrong. One might set the _current_ autoincrement value in all known [to me] db engines, including, but not limited to `mysql` and `postgresql`.